# How to disable tableViewCell selection for a particular part in the UITableView cell iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uitableview

I am new to iOS, now I have a requirement to perform two actions associated with a UITableView cell, I have a check image in my cell, once i click on it i am getting a touch response, but if i tap anywhere other than the image area didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is getting called.

What should i do to achieve calling `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` for only a selected area inside the cell and ignore the remaining area, or disable touches to in few area of cell.

[My layout looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sACig.png)

Comment: can you give a screenshot of you tableviewcell?

Comment: Is the area with disabled touches separate from the image you reference? So the cell has 3 different areas: 1) triggers didSelectRowAtIndexPath, 2) checks your image, 3) doesn't respond to touches?

Comment: @dylansturg : Yes..! not three, but has two areas, 1. Till the check image , and the 2. The check image area. The problem is if i just tap slightly outside the image didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is calling, this i need to make selectable.

Comment: you can add tap gesture on specific area of cell and you don't need to implement didselectrowatindexpath method .

Comment: I am using a custom class for recognition the image tap and getting the proper response too. But as i said above if the user taps slightly outside the image bounds didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is triggered, so that i need to make this area not touchable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your problem. you have to override the **touchesBegan(touches: Set, withEvent event: UIEvent?)** method in your custom UITableViewCell.

```
 class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   var isValidTouch: Bool = true

   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    if let touch = touches.first {
       let point = touch.locationInView(self.contentView)
       let validTouchPoint = self.contentView.bounds.width - (checkMarkView.bounds.width + 16.0) //Trailing + Leading space
        if point.x < validTouchPoint {
            isValidTouch = true
        } else {
            isValidTouch = false
            //Send tap gesture callback to your viewcontroller
        }
    }
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
  }

}
```

In your viewcontroller UITableViewDelegate method just check your touch is valid.

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    if cell.isValidTouch {
      //do whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Set tableview selection style as `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`
2. Implement any of the following delegate method, which stops `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` from getting called.
3. Set `userInteractionEnabled` for your check ImageView and implement the method for image tap (Use `UIButton` or `UIImageView` with *TapGesture*)

   ```
   - (nullable NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
          return nil;    
   }
   ```

   **OR**

   ```
   - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        return NO;
   }
   ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please write this code in *cellForRowAtIndexPath*:

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

If you add check box and uncheck box then write this code in *cellForRowAtIndexPath*

```
if(indexPath.row == 0){
UIButton *btnForCheckAC = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width - 50 , 10,15,15)];
btnForCheckAC.tag = BUSTYPEBTN_TAG;
UIImage *image = (isAcButtonClkd)?[UIImage imageNamed:@"check-mark-pink.png"]:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckbox.png"];

[btnForCheckAC addTarget:self action:@selector(busTypebtnAction:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btnForCheckAC setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                cell.accessoryView = btnForCheckAC;
}
```

Then in  *didSelectedRowAtIndexPath*

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if (indexPath.row == 0) {

       isAcButtonClkd = !isAcButtonClkd;

    }
}
```

Write the *button action*:

```
-(void)busTypebtnAction:(id *)sender event:(id)event{

    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tblBookBus];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tblBookBus indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
        [self tableView: self.tblBookBus didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
    }

}
```

Change the name according to your requirement.

I hope it will help to you.

Answer (score 0):

If your check image is UIBUtton then Try this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.allowsSelection = false;
}
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

First make that imageview as uibutton

and make `cellselectionstyle` as none.

In *cellForRowIndexPath*:

```
{
[cell.CloseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(CrossClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[cell.CloseButton setTag:indexPath.row];

}
```

in Method take the tag value for clicked button row number Like this:

```
-(void)CrossClicked:(UIButton *)sender{

int index = sender.tag;

//on basis of index you can perform all task

}
```